# Resolve HttpClient depends on URL (with/without Proxy)

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

The task is to configure proxy of HttpClient depends on an URL. For example, if an URL contains "hostname.com", must be set.

What is the best practice?

Is the following a solution?

egister different HttpClients in DI as:

```
-- Configured typed HttpClients with different proxies for each service
services.AddHttpClient<Service1>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(GetHttpHandlerSetter(s => s.Service1));
services.AddHttpClient<Service2>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(GetHttpHandlerSetter(s => s.Service2));

-- Configured named HttpClient without proxy
services.AddHttpClient("NoProxy");
```

And Service1 and Service2 will resolve IHttpClientFactory:

```
    public class Service1
{
    readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public IdgwConnectorManager(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
    
    public void Get(string url)
    {
        if (url...)
        {
            _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(Service1));
        }
        else
        {
            _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("NoProxy");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use RestSharp and set a Webproxy for this. A sample if with webproxy at null or complete data will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a client that could be configured in a single location. So you should create a service that would take as ctor parameter the http client and in this place you could configure it for your needs.

**Note**: Typed clients are good candidates for a single backend endpoint. In case of proxied clients i would use named clients instead. And i would use a dictionary to store the client's name with proxy value.

In regards to how you can use the typed client you've created then a more robust solution would be this one:

```
public class Service1
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public Service1(HttpClient client)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        // here you can setup headers, base address
    }

    //encapsulate all logic dealing with the endpoint.
}
```

Now working with DI you could inject this typed client in a consumer class
and from there you can decide whether proxy or non-proxy client is required.

```
public class ConsumerClass
{
    //The typed client can be injected and consumed directly
    private readonly Service1 _service;

    public ConsumerClass(Service1 service)
    {
        _service= service;
    }
    
    //Consume Service1
}
```